# Is it correct to get SQL Server read write ratio from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors?

Tags: sql-server, performance, memory

I'm reading a book and the author taught us a trick to calculate the read write ratio by using `sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors`.

[image]

I suspect the correctness of this method. After a page has been read into memory, we could read from and write to it many times by different transactions. Before a checkpoint, the page will stay dirty in memory and the author just count it as a single write. Is this the right way to calculate SQL Server read write ratio? If not, how can we do that?

Comment: Few answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778199/how-to-figure-the-read-write-ratio-in-sql-server). Another interesting discussion, see the comments section [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2009/06/20/read-write-ratio-versus-read-write-ratio.aspx)